# How to run a command when an app is launched?

Tags: macos, application-launch

Say if I wanted to open Messages and have a command run, how would I do that?

Is there a way to attach a command to the launch of an application?

So like:

```
if (app launched/opened)
run this script
```

?

Comment: Any particular OS/DE?

Comment: If you launch from a script or batch file you can associate anything you like with the launch.

Comment: I know how launch the app from a script, but i want to do it basically the other way around. I want to execute the command by launching the app. My OS is El Capitan